# Is spring web flow compatible with Google App Engine ? Which is the best among facelets we can use with GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is spring web flow compatible with Google App Engine ?

Comment: They used to have a list of frameworks tested in google app enigne; but when I found it, all of the links to that list now redirect to the google group for GAE/J.  :/  But, from what I remember, the spring stuff seemed to run ok but since I no longer have an official document to point you to I'm not posting as an answer.

Comment: @Dave all spring mvc is supported according to Apress.-.Beginning.Java.Google.App.Engine, no mention about Web Flow there

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?80707-Spring-WebFlow-with-Facelets-on-Google-App-Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava) is probably the one Dave was looking for.  It lists a number of frameworks that have been tested with App Engine.  There are several entries for various parts of spring.

Comment: Page is no longer found.